# What technique would you use to find similar people with the same social profile as you? (computer science)

Tags: text, computer-science, data-mining, social-networking

Let's take your Facebook social profile. There are ***interests, activities, movies, music, and tv-shows.***

You have these 5 things, in text, of course.  Given your social profile and 10 other people, we want to find overlaps, similarity, etc.  What method would you use to do it?

I"m guessing it would be best to use vectors and Euclidean/Pearson correlation? That's my approach. What's yours?

Please use a visual-style to answer this question, including examples and/or drawing out the vectors.

Comment: homework question? sure seems like it...

Comment: It's not a homework question...why does everyone think that?

Comment: It's written in the style of a homework question.

Comment: And many of your other questions sound like homework, too.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal?  Because intersection of this textual data is most likely not going to be relevant, save for letting you know that people who are friends sometimes put the same interests into Facebook.

Comment: It's an interesting question,  3k and 100% accept gives him the benefit of the doubt :)

Comment: If it isn't homework, then, by all means, tell us the context for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The December ACM student magazine discussed this area.

http://mags.acm.org/crossroads/2009winter/